# Static factory for PyTypeObject

Tags: python, c, api

I am using the Python C API and trying to create a function that will allocate new instances of PyTypeObjects to use in several C++ classes. The idea is that each class would have a pointer to a PyTypeObject that would get instantiated with this factory. The pointers must be static. 
However, I'm having issues with this approach.

1. In the class that contains the pointer to the PyTypeObject, I get the "undefined reference" linker error when I try to set that static variable equal to the result of the factory function (which is in another class but is static). I suppose this makes sense because the function wouldn't happen until runtime but I don't know another way to do this.
2. I don't know how to set the PyTypeObject fields dynamically because the first field is always a macro: PyObject_VAR_HEAD.

Hope this makes sense. Basically, I'm trying to make it so several classes don't have to redefine PyTypeObject statically, but can instead instantiate their PyTypeObject variables from a factory function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: create a 'template' PyTypeObject, and use struct copying (or memcpy) to clone the basic template. Then you can fill it in with the requisite field definitions after that. This solves (2), since you only have to declare the full PyTypeObject once.

For your first point, you just set the static variable from your module init instead of doing it in the static variable declaration. So, it won't be set until your module actually initializes.

If you plan on doing this often, it may be worth looking at Boost::Python, which simplifies the process of generating CPython wrappers from C++ classes.

Comment: I'm not sure if I know exactly what you mean but a few points:

1. I've heard that doing a memcpy on structs is dangerous, especially this one which has function pointers. Most of the fields are set to 0, but I'm not sure if I want to rely on that. This makes me think I should do a field by field copy, but that silly macro is in the way.
2. What do you mean set the static PyTypeObject in the module init? I don't know exactly what you mean, but note that I am embedding Python, so I must explicitly call the init routine. Python will not call it since I'm not providing it as an exported function.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with memcpy'ing structs, even if they contain pointers. The problem is if you free references to struct members without updating or considering all copies.

Besides, memcpy/struct copy *is* a field-by-field copy. There's no difference.

Comment: When you initialize your Python interpreter, then, you would set the PyTypeObject static variable. Just do it before the spot where you would normally do a PyType_Ready.